# Comparing multiple JSON files to master JSON file in C++

Tags: c++, json

I am trying to find a way to compare multiple JSON file to a "master" JSON file. The master file includes all necessary info, but the other files are missing some. I have been able to locate a few different libraries for JSON in C++, but I haven't been able to find any functions that can diff the files with the master and output the differences.

Does anyone know if there is a good function for this?

Comment: I would run the files through `jq` to give them consistent formatting, then use standard diff tools. Don't think this is something you need to manually build in C++ (unless there is something more specific that you want).

Comment: @MartinYork That looks like a very handy tool, glad I visited this question.

Comment: @MartinYork: "Give them consistent formatting" sounds like a job for a "JSON Tidy" tool (of which there are many).  A sed-like tool seems like it would need a lot of configuration to have the same effect.

Comment: I don't need to manually do this with C++, however, I am required to use a library to solve this problem.. By using a standard diff tool, I do not think this will achieve the objective based on the guidelines I was given..